# How do I draw the markers based upon current map canvas, as a user traverses the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have successfully drawn the markers using google maps API.

```
var latlng = {lat: 34.7651458,lng: 121.453208};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: latlng,
  zoom: 18
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Marker!'
});
marker.setMap(map);
```

But, if a user traverses the map then `centre:latlng` changes. If I want to draw a new marker, for this new `centre`, how do I capture that change in `centre` to fetch data from API for new marker to be drawn.  Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `dragend` event listener to the `map`(or you can also use `center_changed`). Get the center of the map using `map.getCenter()` and create a marker.

```
map.addListener('dragend', function() {
    var c = map.getCenter();                   //Get new center of the map

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({      //Create a new marker and use the map's center as the location.
        position: c,
        map: map,
        title: 'Marker!'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, Sir. Now, I could put my logic in that function to fetch data from API. Is there any difference in `centre_changed` and `dragend`?

Comment: Yeah it's curious , wouldn't a drag always change the center? unless you could drag in an circular arc fashion.

Comment: Yes, there are differences. You can check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events for more info. Center change can be changed without dragging though. Like when you change map location programmatically :)

Comment: @Eddie: One last question - In my case, centre would change only when the user traverses the map(drags it). And, when this drag ends, I need to capture the new centre and draw the new markers. `dragend` seems to be best suited for me, any opinion, sir...

Comment: @Viney: Thanks for that circular arc drag thing, Sir, must take care of that while selecting events.

Comment: @ksalf Yeah, if that is the case `dragend` suited for your app :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help and that nice link, Sir. Going ahead with 'dragend` :)

Comment: Got the power to upvote an answer, upvoted yours, Sir.